# Need help implementing Start/Resume/Pause/Stop thread operations on selfmade Hamster Simulator

Tags: java, multithreading

**The Project:**

> Completely recreate the known Hamster Simulator using Java, currently working on buttons to start/pause/resume/stop the simulation, which is running as a Thread. [Screenshot of current progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmqM8.png)

**The Problem:**

> As the user can input loops into the editor, my usual method of using while(!stopped) does not work because this loop only ends after the loop the user has input has ended. See walkInCircles() from the picture above for explanation, with this kind of input the hardcoded while(!stopped) would never be left.

**The MCVE Code**

> ```
> public class RunnableGame extends Thread {
>
> private final Object lock = new Object();
> private volatile boolean suspend = false, stopped = false; 
>
>   @Override
>     public void run() {
>      while (!stopped){        //This loop will not be left if the user inputs any loops
>         while (!suspend){    //This loop will not be left if the user inputs any loops
>                 /* Stripped down for readability
>                 method.invoke();
>                 updateObserver();
>                 */
>         }
>         synchronized (lock){
>             try {
>                 lock.wait();
>             } catch (InterruptedException ie){
>                 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
>                 return;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
>   public void suspendThread(){
>     suspend = true;
> }
>
>   public void stopThread(){
>     suspend = true;
>     stopped = true;
>     synchronized (lock) {
>         lock.notifyAll();
>     }
> }
>
>   public void resumeThread(){
>     suspend = false;
>     synchronized (lock) {
>         lock.notifyAll();
>     }
> }
> ```

**What I need**

> A different way to start/pause/resume/stop a Thread in Java.

Thank you very much in forward <3

Comment: How is user input executed? Via recursion? Or are you interpreting the code in any fashion yourself?

Comment: I'll +1 this just for the words "hamster simulation".

Comment: @CPUTerminator The code input is wrapped with the predetermined prefix "public class AkteurProgramm extends model.Actor { public" and the postfix "}" which gets stored in a local .java. This java file is getting compiled via the JavaCompiler included in the Java SDK. Afterwards the main method of said code is invoked in the code snippet above. I have been given access to a working copy but I'm having a hard time going through it and finding the correspondent part. All I could find yet was some boolean flags similar to mine, but nothing concerning my problem. Will report when I have found smth.

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying a lack of infinite loops, I feel like this problem is inherently impossible. If the method supplied is infinite in duration and your class never gets passed priority from that method then you have no way of interacting with it until it terminates.

Basically, the `interrupted` status is a convention that `Thread` subclasses and `Runnables` have to follow: If the thread you're in ever becomes interrupted you have to stop what you're doing and either handle it or terminate the thread entirely. By allowing the user to input a custom method (that may contain an infinite loop), you're allowing for the creation of methods that don't respect its running thread interrupted status, which means that no configuration of `interrupt()` calls will ever do the trick.

All this is a bit reminiscent of the halting problem, in that you're trying to interact with a subroutine that may go on forever without ever telling the outer routine any new information. I'm not sure it's actually solvable.

The easiest alternative is to require (informally) that methods inputted by users correspond to only a single step of whatever loop they want to run. Then between steps you can do the interrupted status checking yourself, and I would think your current code would work for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement (at least from what I read) that the outer routine not modify the inner routine (user code). As I am unsure how you are executing this user code, I can only be vague as to how you approach to solve this issue.

Given that you have the power over executing the given code, you can simply parse the code and drop in your suspend/stop check conditions as part of requirement for the loop to continue execution.

This can be accomplished in many ways with the simplest being via direct symbolic replacement. Filtering out segments for strings and such, something like:

```
replace("while(", "while(!suspend && !stop &&");
```

will do the trick (accounting for possible whitespace/newline and all sorts of combinations in between).

This technique should be extended to for loops as well.

Additionally, you should interrupt the thread to cancel any potential long running tasks that user-code throws (such as `Thread.sleep()`). And absorb exceptions that result from the user code.

Given you seem to be able to parse user code directly, compile and then execute within your own code body, techniques described here should be feasible in your program. The best thing you can do is to either restrict what users can type or to make invisible amendments to user code without adversely affecting the execution of said code.

Whether its possible to encompass everything the user can possibly type and have it still function normally is a question in which I don't know the answer to. Though, a simple call to `System.exit(0)` from within the user code seems to do the trick :)

Comment: Could still run into issues with recursion though.

Comment: @Mshnik Prior to function calls, you could perform a if-statement to the suspend/stop conditions and throw an exception (should cure recursion).

Comment: Ah true. The only other thing I'd worry about (because i was thinking of a similar answer initially) is that suspending and resuming will start from the top of the method, not from where you resumed it.

Comment: @Mshnik The task at hand is very difficult, especially if you allow users complete freedom of what to type. Keeping up java "best practices" whilst maintaining the feature-set required may be downright impossible. The code that would result from making something that allow suspend/continue and complete halts of arbitrary user code will look somewhat like a mini java debugger with line breaks. And we all know how hard it would be to implement something like that from scratch. If OP can accept that user code will be completely re-run upon suspend, it'll simplify things.

Comment: Entirely agreed. I didn't mean to be all negative, just to point out that any reasonable solution is still fragile because of the wide range of input. If the suspend/resume requirement is dropped,  then I'd say your answer is perfect